# Icon export @x ratio from iPhone 5 to 6+?

Tags: iphone, ios, icon, resolution, design

If I’m designing icons/images in native iPhone 5 resolution, what @x multiple do I need to export them at for iPhone 6+? Just use @2x? That’s too big right? Example: an icon is 44px x 44px. If I export at @2x it’s 88px. That’s too large for 6+ right? What’s the right multiple or ratio from 5 to 6+.

In the past, from non-retina to retina the ratio was just doubled. So an icon of 22px would be 44px. Very annoying for Apple to do this... :/

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ricardo is correct in his answer of @3x, but I'll take a shot at answering your question as well.

If you're working from Retina resolution assets already, the upscale factor would be an additional 1.5x for the iPhone 6 Plus.

For example, your 88px by 88px Retina icon would have to be up-scaled to a resolution one and a half times that amount for the iPhone Six Plus: 88*1.5=132 .

Answer (score 0):

Check this chart : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/iconmatrix.html

So for your answer iPhone 6 Plus is @3x

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for. I know about the design guidelines. In my question I said I'm working from @2x size already. If I'm working at retina size already, how much % do I need to increase my icons by? 150% or 200%?